How to view of the physical disk of a network share is an HDD or SSD?
I use PowerShell "Get-PhysicalDisk | Format-Table -AutoSize" on cmd to check if the physical disk of my local computer is a SSD or HDD. Is this possible to check this for mounted network shares?

No, a network share doesn't expose this kind of information.

Depending on what information you are wanting you can try:
From Powershell:
Get-WmiObject CIM_DiskDrive -ComputerName <network host>
Get-WmiObject CIM_PhysicalMedia -ComputerName <network host>

or if you want to do it oldschool in cmd:
wmic /NODE:<network path> PATH Select * from Win32_DiskDrive

Both commands have more classes that have information about your drive.
To get a list of all the classes that you access run
get-cimclass * -Namespace root\cimv2

or for classes that contain the word disk only:
get-cimclass *disk* -Namespace root\cimv2

You should be able to get all the info you need this way
